# How to Write applicaition on Mifare Desfire EV2 NFC badge

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare, ndef, nxp-microcontroller

I want to write a simple application (open URL in the Browser) on a Mifare Desfire EV2 badge. There is already a non-NDEF proprietary format application on the badge. The badge supplier confirms the badge is not blocked for writing on it and there is enough space for a simple URL.

I downloaded more than 10 apps from the Play Store. No success. Example NXP Tag Writer app won't write on it because it'S not NDEF format. It also won't let me format the unused part of the badge.